# How to specify the minSdkVersion in react native project

Tags: react-native, create-react-native-app, android-min-sdk

I have created react native project using [create-react-native-app](https://github.com/react-community/create-react-native-app)

I can see that there is a `sdkVersion` property in `app.json`, but I want to specify `minSdkVersion` for the app.

How do I specify the `minSdkVersion` in react native project?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You can change it from `app/build.gradle` directly 
Open the project go to the `android/app` folder and open  `build.gradle` file.
In this you can find

```
   defaultConfig {
    applicationId "PACKAGE_ID"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 27
    versionCode 1
    versionName "1.0"
    multiDexEnabled true
    ndk {
        abiFilters "armeabi-v7a", "x86"
    }
}
```

change this `minSdkVersion 16` according to your requirement

Comment: For newer versions of React Native it seems this answer is better: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58750145/5552415. Remember there are two build.gradle files. The one in android/app may have rootProject.ext.minSdkVersion instead of a number, so just go into the parent directory and change the minSdkVersion like in the other answer I suggested.

Answer (score 6):

I have these settings in the android\build.gradle file as per below...

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        supportLibVersion = "28.0.0"
        buildToolsVersion = "28.0.3"
        minSdkVersion = 23
        compileSdkVersion = 28
        targetSdkVersion = 28
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You might like to notice that react-native lib/package/module (as you wish) sets the `minSdkVersion` to `16`. You can see it here on their official build.gradle file:

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 28

    ...

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion(16)
        targetSdkVersion(28)
        versionCode(1)
        versionName("1.0")
    }

    ...
}
```

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/7a72c35a20a18c19bf6ab883cb2c53a85bd4c5c0/ReactAndroid/build.gradle#L356

By setting `minSdkVersion` to `16`, react-native uses Android API's natively supported by at least KitKat version.

[image: This section provides data about the relative number of devices running a given version of the Android platform.]

You may see the official Platform Version Dashboard here:
https://developer.android.com/about/dashboards/index.html