# Can't build apk in react native

Tags: android, react-native, gradle, mobile, apk

I have a task to build apk applications with react native, I watched this video to understand how to do it and took the same code
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5tgcogEoIiQ&t=590s

https://github.com/mahdi-sharifimehr/RN-Tutorial-Main/tree/RN-Tutorial-35
I got such an error:

```
> Task :app:processDebugManifest FAILED
Type 'ProcessApplicationManifest': static method 'getArtifactName()' should not be annotated with: @Internal. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks for more details.
Type 'ProcessApplicationManifest': static method 'getNameFromAutoNamespacedManifest()' should not be annotated with: @Internal. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks for more details.
/root/escrow_checker/apps/RN-Tutorial-Main-RN-Tutorial-35/android/app/src/debug/AndroidManifest.xml Error:
        uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0] /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/af47c244ab2af63c65c98f6eb4516ef2/jetified-react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
        Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
                or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
                or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook.react" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

See http://g.co/androidstudio/manifest-merger for more information about the manifest merger.


FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed : uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library [com.facebook.react:react-native:0.71.0-rc.0] /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/af47c244ab2af63c65c98f6eb4516ef2/jetified-react-native-0.71.0-rc.0-debug/AndroidManifest.xml as the library might be using APIs not available in 16
        Suggestion: use a compatible library with a minSdk of at most 16,
                or increase this project's minSdk version to at least 21,
                or use tools:overrideLibrary="com.facebook.react" to force usage (may lead to runtime failures)

* Try:
Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

* Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 19s
```

found a solution on the Internet and changed minSdkVersion in build.gradle to 23, but now I get such an error:

```
> Task :app:processDebugResources FAILED
Type 'LinkApplicationAndroidResourcesTask': non-property method 'canHaveSplits()' should not be annotated with: @Input. This behaviour has been deprecated and is scheduled to be removed in Gradle 7.0. See https://docs.gradle.org/6.2/userguide/more_about_tasks.html#sec:up_to_date_checks for more details.

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.Workers$ActionFacade
   > Android resource linking failed
     /root/.gradle/caches/transforms-2/files-2.1/991cf6dc746cd39d23cce3c15a61bfa7/core-1.7.0/res/values/values.xml:105:5-114:25: AAPT: error: resource android:attr/lStar not found.
```

please tell me what's wrong and why I can't easily build the apk, here are my actions
in main directory
npm install
cd android
chmod +x ./gradlew
./gradlew assembleDebug

Gradle version Gradle 7.4.2

I don’t understand why it doesn’t want to build, in theory I should have got apk

Answer (score 1, accepted):

" uses-sdk:minSdkVersion 16 cannot be smaller than version 21 declared in library "

Looks like your minSdkVersion isn't compatible with your facebook library you're using. What kind of React Native project are you using?

If it's expo managed you'll need this: https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/build-properties/

If it's a non-expo project, you can easily go into the Android files on your own. This link will help you: [How to specify the minSdkVersion in react native project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51503218/how-to-specify-the-minsdkversion-in-react-native-project)

It's likely that you just need to change the 16 to a 21 and it'll build.

Comment: I changed it in this project as in the second link that you sent, but now I started getting an error that is described below

Comment: I looked up the error for the 2nd part and it says there's memory problems.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57606462/a-failure-occurred-while-executing-com-android-build-gradle-internal-tasks

Says its a quick fix too. Increase the memory allocation by going into the gradle.properties file

Comment: You were right, thank you very much, I don’t write in js, I didn’t change everything that is necessary and there were mistakes, thank you very much :)